# String is working but in variable not working string to date

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 private void updateTime()
    {
        string getDateTimeNow = TimeManager.sharedInstance.getDT(); //string output: 10-16-2019 22:23:48
        Debug.Log("get time now is: " + getDateTimeNow); //string output: 10-16-2019 22:23:48
        string format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(getDateTimeNow, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

The output in get getDateTimeNow is: "10-16-2019 22:23:48" but when i try to parse the string variable getDateTimeNow it gives me an error FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I edited the code sorry just a typo

Comment: What you've described works, per [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ih6G7A). Are you sure the details are correct?

Comment: what is the value of `getDateTimeNow` as `10-16-2019 22:23:48` will work and `10-16-2019` does not

Comment: You say that it logs 10-16-2019 without the time.

Comment: Also why does something called a `TimeManager` return a `string` instead of a `DateTime`?

Comment: It comes from an another class that outputs the date and time from the server